# Mantaining state for a list of documents without storing them in the database or the file sistem

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Hi I have a situation where I need to upload multiple files from a FileUpload controler and display them on the page.

This may be a stupid question because I have no experience in webforms what so ever , but I need to be able to maintain the files on the page without storing them in the database or on the server until the user actually presses the post button.

My experience is related more to ASP.NET MVC and WEB API.

Each time the user uploads a new file the file get's displayed on the page this is how the functionality looks:

[image]

When the use presses the button I should be able to have access to all the files so I can store them in the database and on the filesistem.

Because of the way the database was designed I can store the file on the database so I can keep track of it until the user writes something in the teaxtareaand posts the data.

The only thing that comes to mind is storing the files in Session , but a collegue suggested that I should store only the fileName in the session and store the file Content in bytes somewhere else.

I then tought of actualy getting the path of the file and to store it along side with the fileName in session but looking at the FileUpload object I do not seem to have access to the filePath.

My last ideea is to store the file contet in a hidden input but while debugging I realized that each time I upload a new file the Page_Load get's runed and from what litle I know about webforms that means a page refresh making it loose the hidden input's along with there data.

Can anyone suggesst a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely *not* store the files in session. Storing the files in a temporary folder with a GUID (since we want them to be unique) for a name and storing those names in session is a good idea. If you want to keep the original file names you can just append the GUID to the file name. You just need to remember to delete the files from the temp folder once you're done, and perhaps (for added safety) run a scheduled task that deletes unneeded files from the temp folder.